# Tikz borders not working after using the package Polyglossia

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, nodes, polyglossia, border

First I tried this bit of code, it's working fine, the results are as expected:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}


\newcommand{\jamanta}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
    \draw [blue,line width=2mm]
    (current page.south west)
    rectangle
    (current page.north east)
    ;}

\newcommand{\greenborders}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw [green]
    (current page text area.south west)
    rectangle
    (current page text area.north east)
    ;}

\chead[\jamanta]{\jamanta} % for page borders

%\chead[\greenborders]{\greenborders} %for margin borders

\begin{document}


\section{A}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{B}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: Page result before adding polyglossia]
the moment polyglossia kicks in, it seems that `current page.south west` goes to a completely wrong position.

[image: Page result after adding polyglossia]
I use xelatex (of course) to compile my documents, I don't know if this has to do with it.

The link to my log file after adding the polyglossia package:
https://pastebin.com/r4ifPQfm

Comment: how exactly are you using polygossia? Add it to the example.

Comment: Did you try to compiling your document more than one?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Just using the package causes the issue, I  didn't even use any command yet.

Comment: I had no problems when I added it. So either the exact place in the preamble matters, or you package versions.  Extend the example and show your log file.

Comment: @ferahfeza yeah I did, could this be the problem? and if so, how can I solve it? I need to compile the document many times so I can preview the document. I use WSL ubuntu 18.04, and preview the document using the browser by making an http-server. if there's a better way I'd love to hear it out.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry I didn't notice your response as it was instant before I even wrote the other one, I'll add the link now.

Comment: well it works fine for me, but I have a current texlive 2020, and you have an 3 years old system. Quite possible that there was bug which has been resolved in the meantime.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that's pretty weird, I've just updated my ubuntu repos before installing latex, I'll try to update it again and see if I can upgrade the packages. thank you in advance, I'll let you know when it's done installing.

Comment: texlive system in linux distros are often outdated. If you want a real up-to-date tex system you should install a vanilla texlive.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well, I installed the 2020 version but still, the same issue, is there a way to debug in latex? at least print out the coords of (current page.south west)

Comment: Edit your example so that it shows exactly what you are compiling, compile at least twice and show the new log file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sure, I think it's using the old installation to compile but when I do `xelatex --version` it shows the 2019 version (which I just installed, the old one was 2017).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh man, I'm grateful for you, it's working now, I just had to remove the old latex, thank you so much, can't appreciate your help enough. if you wish you can add your solution and I'll mark it as correct so others may benefit from the solution.